# JLabel Image Icon Placeholder always return 0 in constructor. Unable to load Blob

Tags: java, swing, blob, jlabel

I'm having problems auto-loading the `BLOB` that I'm selecting from the database through the use of a method which I'm calling in the constructor. 
Everything else (inserting the picture, updating it) is working fine except the auto-retrieving of images per user logged in.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero
    at java.awt.image.ReplicateScaleFilter.<init>(ReplicateScaleFilter.java:102)
    at java.awt.image.AreaAveragingScaleFilter.<init>(AreaAveragingScaleFilter.java:77)
```

My Method definition,

```
private void loadProfilePic(){
        String SQL = "SELECT PROFILE_PIC from allusers_profile_picture WHERE USERID =?";
        try(Connection con = DBUtil.getConnection(DBType.MYSQL);
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SQL);)
        {
            ps.setInt(1,userId);
            try(ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,profilePicJlbl.getWidth()+" "+profilePicJlbl.getHeight());
                if(rs.next()){
                    byte[] img = rs.getBytes("PROFILE_PIC");
                    ImageIcon myImageIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
                    Image image = myImageIcon.getImage();
                    Image myImage = image.getScaledInstance
                        (profilePicJlbl.getWidth(), profilePicJlbl.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                    ImageIcon finalImage = new ImageIcon(myImage);
                    profilePicJlbl.setIcon(finalImage);
                }
            } //--end of inner try
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error: "+e.getMessage());
        } //--end of catch
    }//--end of method
```

Then I call it inside the constructor.

```
public home(int uId,String uname,String uType) {
        loadProfilePic();
}
```

I can't think of any reason why it would return 0. But I read somewhere that the JLabel's width and height is 0 until rendered.

[image]

How can I solve this? I don't want the user to click on a separate button just to load the profile pic. It has to be automatic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes a component's width and height are 0 before rendering. Why are you even getting the label's width before rendering? Why do you need this? A solution is to get rid of this requirement.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for your response. I need to be able to select the blob from the database once the profile panel is created. What alternative or options can you suggest?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the marked property with the method `getPreferredSize().width`.
If the `JLabel` is not displaying `getWidth` returns 0.

As stated by Hovercraft, why don't you use a constant to establish your preferred size for user's image?